# $watch() isn't updating the $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have the following controller, and when I call `$scope.remove()` it makes a request to the usercart, which makes a request to the api. The api returns json object which has an object with an array of cart items.

The html on the page uses an `ng-repeat` to loop through the items, but the page isn't updating for some reason, and I can not figure out why.

```
// Main controller
app.controller('Checkout', function($scope, usercart){

    $scope.cart = [];

    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return usercart.cart;
    }, function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(newVal !== oldVal){
            $scope.cart = newVal;
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.remove = function(domain){
        usercart.remove(domain);
    };

});
```

This service makes a request to the api and saves the cart data.

```
// User cart service
app.service('usercart', function(cart){
    this.remove = function(domain){
        // cart is an api service to make http requests
        cart.removeDomain(domain).success(function(data){
            this.cart = data.cart;
        });
    };
});
```

Here is a json response example:

```
{
    "message":"Success",
    "cart":[{
        "domain":"asdfsadfsadf.org",
        "years":2,
        "amount":9
    },{
        "domain":"asdsmembers.cc",
        "years":2,
        "amount":24.95
    },{
        "domain":"asdsmembers.tv",
        "years":2,
        "amount":39.95
    }]
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in cart">
    <td data-th="Product">
        {{i.domain}}
    </td>
    <td data-th="Price">${{i.amount|number:2}}</td>
    <td data-th="Quantity">
        <select ng-model="i.years" ng-options="y.value as y.name for y in selYears" ng-disable="isInCart(i.domain)" ng-class="{disabled: isInCart(i.domain)}" ng-change="update(i.domain, 'years', i.years)"></select>
    </td>
    <td class="actions" data-th="" align="center">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="background: #333;" ng-click="remove(i.domain)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff;"></span></button>
    </td>
    <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">${{i.years * i.amount|number:2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also when the page loads the table displays fine. It is just when I run the remove function.

Comment: Can you show us your model/template (HTML) ?

Comment: Okay I have added the HTML

Comment: just a coment on your html. you can change `<td data-th="Price">${{i.amount|number:2}}</td>` to `<td data-th="Price">{{i.amount|currency}}</td>`

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope there are no errors

Comment: you don't need that watcher. You can get cleaner code if you check out my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried but i believe here is the problem

```
cart.removeDomain(domain).success(function(data){
        this.cart = data.cart;
    });
```

Since `this` is a pointer to the caller of the callback function you will create `cart` property onto your `cart` api service. In order to circumvent this issue you should create variable called (by convention) `self` and assign `this` to it (at the begining of the `usercart` service):

```
var self = this;
```

after that, change your code into this:

```
cart.removeDomain(domain).success(function(data){
        self.cart = data.cart;
    });
```

To get better understanding you can go through this [post](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Comment: Ahh yes, that is correct. I used `$this = this` and updated it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Watching your local `$scope` for a value you change in your singleton `usercart` definitely wouldn't work, unless you explicitely passed in that local scope. We can simplify this by ridding the `$watch` and resolving a promise we can return from our service instead. This allows for generic re-use and alleviates watchers from polluting our controllers. Observe the following changes...

```
app.service('usercart', function(cart) {
    this.remove = function(domain) {
        return cart.removeDomain(domain) // return promise
    };
});
```

---

```
app.controller('Checkout', function($scope, usercart) {
    $scope.remove = function(domain) {
        usercart.remove(domain).then(function(data) { // resolve promise
            $scope.cart = data.cart;
        });
    };
});
```